# Can I reference secrets in my firebase.json file

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am in the process of converting my google cloud functions to firebase functions, previosly i have a gcloud command with --set-secrets to set my secrets. I see there is a similar way to store secrets in firebase.json files, check this schema (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/master/schema/firebase-config.json).
My secrets are stored in secrets manager and are referenced via
MY_SECRET= "path-in-secret-manager"

How can i pass these secrets in my firebase.json file where the schema for secrets (under definitions/frameworkBackendOptions) is like this:
"secrets": {
"items": {
"type": "string"
},
"type": "array"
},

I tried having it in an object format, not sure that will be valid though.

Answer (score 0):

When a secret is placed in the secret manager and it is in the same project. Then these secret are available for the Firebase cloud function, not sure about the emulator suite. Look at the process variable.